# Error when logging into user SQL Item with the same name already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I am using magento CE V1.9.2.1 on CentOS and have an issue where an error is generated when going to a user account on the front end.

Error says "Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "105" already exist", I tried disabling the product, recompiling, clearing the caches and reindexing.

I have command line access and great experience but new to Magento.

File generated in var/reports looks like this:

```
     a:5:{i:0;s:1709:"Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "105" already exist. 
SQL that caused this: SELECT `e`.*, `t_compare`.`product_id`, `t_compare`.`customer_id`, `t_compare`.`visitor_id`, `t_compare`.`store_id` AS `item_store_id`, `t_compare`.`catalog_compare_item_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `cat_index`.`visibility`, `store_cat_index`.`visibility` AS `store_visibility`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
     INNER JOIN `catalog_compare_item` AS `t_compare` ON (t_compare.product_id=e.entity_id) AND (t_compare.customer_id = '41813')
     INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
     LEFT JOIN `core_store` AS `store_index` ON store_index.store_id = t_compare.store_id
     LEFT JOIN `core_store_group` AS `store_group_index` ON store_index.group_id = store_group_index.group_id
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `store_cat_index` ON store_cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id AND store_cat_index.store_id = t_compare.store_id AND store_cat_index.category_id=store_group_index.root_category_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1' WHERE (cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) OR store_cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4))";i:1;s:3338:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.php(265): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.php(1055): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(5691): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml(30): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare->getItemCollection()
    #5 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(3418): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
    #6 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(3449): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
    #7 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(3463): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #8 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #9 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(13851): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #10 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
    #11 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(2331): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #12 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(2275): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
    #13 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(50): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
    #14 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(3418): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
    #15 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(3449): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
    #16 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(3463): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #17 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #18 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(28559): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #19 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(14244): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #20 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(115): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #21 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
    #22 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(18726): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #23 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(18256): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #24 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/includes/src/__default.php(21084): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #25 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #26 /var/www/vhosts/ushcgshots.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: I just solved this but can't figure out why it got that way. Maybe a Magento expert can answer. The problem was double records in the compare table 'catalog_compare_item', I simply deleted the doubles and it went away. Should this table not prevent this type of entry?

Answer (score 0):

[How did I fix «**Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "…" already exist**» on loading `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Compare_Item_Collection` in Magento 1](https://mage2.pro/t/6435)